# Folders (sub directories incl.) and files moved if it's a specific date to a specific folder for backup purposes. The rest needs to be deleted

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my first time on stackoverflow and would appreciate some help on this specific topic that I am struggling with for a while now. I have been searching around and so far no solution has helped. My problem is the following:

I want to look through different folders and sub directories and move files that are a specific date using a ***BATCH*** file and the rest should be deleted.This is for routine maintenance.

The folder layout is as follows, just as an example:

```
C:\Batch\Test1  
|Kent  
  |New Folder  
    |New Folder   
      28_02.txt  
|Jordan Hal  
|Wayne Bruce  
  27_02.txt  
  26_02_Backup.txt  
  28_02_Backup.rar
```

This is the code that I have thus far:

```
@echo off

for /d %%a in ("C:\Batch\Test1\*") do (  
  for /d %%b in ("C:\Batch\Test1\%%a\*") do (  
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Batch\Backup\%%~nxa\%%~nxb" MD "C:\Batch\Backup\%%~nxa\%%~nxb"  
    forfiles /p "%%~b" /m *.* /d -02/29/2013 /c "cmd /c move @file  "C:\Batch\Backup\%%~nxa\%%~nxb""  
    RD /s /q "C:\Batch\Test1\%%~nxa" 2>"C:\Batch\Backup\log.txt"  
  )  
)  

pause
```

It only backups the folders, but not the sub directories and the files.

Thanks in advance! ;P

Comment: Several questions arise. Do you want to backup files that were changed *at* a particular date, or do you want to backup files that were changed *before* a particular date? Do you want to keep the folder structure, or do you want all files to go directly into the backup directory? If you want to backup folders as well: do you want the backup to include all files and subfolders in them, regardless of *their* last modification date?

Comment: I want the folder structure to stay exactly the same, so it would be the same structure, just in the Backup folder. I want the files and folders to be backed up in the backup folder exactly the way they are, but only the files that have an older date than the specific date, needs to be backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It was made for this kind of task.

```
robocopy "C:\Batch\Test1" "C:\Batch\Backup" /s /minage:20130229
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked on a different approach that looks like the following:  @echo off  move "C:\123\Ori - Copy" C:\123\Backup  cd Backup  forfiles -p "C:\123\Backup" -s -m *.* -d -0 -c "cmd /c del @path"  pause